# Core Location is not working Swift iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift

**Getting this warning and core location is not working:**

*This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
  if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
     // Your code example
     self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
  }
}
```